# Deleted data remains on a disk until?

Tags: operating-systems, memory-hardware, filesystems

I am little bit confused between the two answers below.
What is the exact answer of this question?

My query is,
"Deleted data remains on a disk until...?"

1. The data is overwritten;
2. The recycle bin is emptied.

I have searched it over internet and books, but I have found various answers.
Please explain to me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the file system used and preferences provided, but in the most common case - deleted data is marked as deleted (dirty) and is used when some new data is to be written.  Priority of usage of dirty block earlier than empty depends on system preferences.

The recycle bin is different case - until emptied there is guarantee to recover files, so it is not deleted per se.
After recycle bin is emptied file is deleted (so flagged as deleted and then based on preferences stays there or is physically deleted).

Comment: So the correct answer is  1-the data is overwritten . Am I right?

Comment: Yes, 1. But 2 will downgrade to 1.